# How to add a new Orderer Organization to existing Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

I am trying to add a new Orderer Organization to RAFT based existing ordering service. I am using the `first-network` from `fabric-samples` as the base network. While generating crypto-material, I have modified to generate crypto-material for 1 more orderer organization. The `crypto-config.yaml` looks like:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
      - Hostname: orderer2
      - Hostname: orderer3
      - Hostname: orderer4
      - Hostname: orderer5
  - Name: Orderer1
    Domain: example1.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
      - Hostname: orderer2
      - Hostname: orderer3

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Also, the `configtx.yaml` for creating new Orderer organization's MSP in JSON format is given as:

```
Organizations:
    - &Orderer1Org
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Orderer1Org

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Orderer1MSP

        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example1.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orderer1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orderer1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orderer1MSP.admin')"
```

Then I boot up the the network using `byfn.sh`. Now I use the `cli` container to modify the **system channel** configuration in following steps:

1. First I add the organization's JSON to the **Orderer** group as follows and submit channel update:

   jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Orderer":{"groups": {"Orderer1Org":.[1]}}}}}' config.json orderer1org.json > modified_config.json
2. Then I add organization's JSON to the **Consortium** group as follows and submit channel update:

   jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Consortiums":{"groups":{"SampleConsortium":{"groups": {"Orderer1MSP":.[1]}}}}}}}' config1.json orderer1org.json > modified_config1.json
3. Then I add organization's **orderer1** TLS certificates to **Consenters** section and submit channel update:

   cert=`base64 ../crypto/ordererOrganizations/example1.com/orderers/orderer.example1.com/tls/server.crt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'`

   cat modified_config1.json | jq '.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert'", "host": "orderer.example1.com", "port": 7050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert'"}] ' > modified_config2.json
4. Then I update the system channel configuration's **Application** group with new Orderer Org's JSON:

   jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"Orderer1Org":.[1]}}}}}' config.json orderer1org.json > modified_config.json

Then I start one of the orderers in the new organization (`orderer.example1.com`) but the container is failing with following error:

```
2020-04-09 13:09:05.600 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication] fetchLastBlockSeq -> WARN 0e8 Received status:FORBIDDEN  from orderer.example.com:7050: forbidden pulling the cha
nnel
2020-04-09 13:09:05.600 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication] func1 -> WARN 0e9 Received error of type 'forbidden pulling the channel' from {orderer.example.com:7050 [certs]}
```

The `orderer.example.com` logs throw this error:

```
2020-04-09 13:28:59.338 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO a3c Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authorit
y) for identity 0
2020-04-09 13:28:59.338 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO a3d Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authorit
y) for identity 0
2020-04-09 13:28:59.339 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO a3e Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authorit
y) for identity 0
2020-04-09 13:28:59.340 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO a3f Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authorit
y) for identity 0
2020-04-09 13:28:59.340 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN a40 [channel: byfn-sys-channel] Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 172.25.0.15:36196: implic
it policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
2020-04-09 13:28:59.341 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a41 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.15:36196
 grpc.peer_subject="CN=orderer.example1.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.992078ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to extend the `first-network` by adding a new Orderer Organization as follows:

1. Start the `first-network` through the `byfn.sh` script in the `fabric-samples` repo in the `etcdraft` mode.
2. I generated crypto-material like described in the `crypto-config.yaml` in the question above.
3. Use the `configtxgen` tool to print the new orderer organization's MSP into JSON format.
4. Mount or `docker cp` this JSON file to the running `cli` container.
5. Set the environment inside the `cli` container corresponding to existing ordering node. Import the latest `system-channel` configuration. Decode it to JSON format.
6. Edit the system channel configuration block's `Orderer` section to add the new orderer organization's MSP as follows:

   `jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Orderer":{"groups": {"Orderer1Org":.[1]}}}}}' config.json orderer1org.json > config1.json`
7. Edit the system channel configuration block's `Consortiums` section to add the new orderer organization's MSP as follows:

   `jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Consortiums":{"groups":{"SampleConsortium":{"groups": {"Orderer1MSP":.[1]}}}}}}}' config1.json orderer1org.json > config2.json`
8. Edit the system channel configuration block's `Consenters` section to add the TLS credentials for the new orderer organization's `orderer.example1.com` node as follows:

   `` cert=`base64 ../crypto/ordererOrganizations/example1.com/orderers/orderer.example1.com/tls/server.crt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'` ``

   `cat config2.json | jq '.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert'", "host": "orderer.example1.com", "port": 7050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert'"}] ' > modified_config.json`
9. Encode the block, find delta, create channel update transaction, encode it as protobuf envelope and submit the channel update transaction.
10. Fetch the latest system channel configuration block.
11. Start one of the orderers (the one who was added to consenters list previously) using this latest fetched system channel configuration block as it's `genesis.block` file.
12. Perform `docker exec` into the `cli` container. Using the environment of an existing orderer node, fetch the latest system channel configuration.
13. Edit the system channel configuration block to add the new orderer's endpoint in the `OrdererAddresses` section as follows:

    `cat config.json | jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses += ["orderer.example1.com:7050"] ' > modified_config.json`
14. Encode the block, find delta, create channel update transaction, encode it as protobuf envelope and get the block signed by `Orderer1Org` admin to satify the `mod_policy` for `/Channel/OrdererAddresses` resource which is set to `Admins` policy. This implicit meta policy expects the signature of `MAJORITY Admins` at that level of update. So, as the number of orderer organizations are 2 now, we need both the organization's admins to sign this system channel update transaction. Set the environment corresponding to `Orderer1Org` admin and run the following command:

    `peer channel signconfigtx -f ordorg_update_in_envelope.pb`
15. Set the environment back to `OrdererOrg` admin and submit the channel update transaction. The `peer channel update` will automatically sign the transaction on behalf of OrdererOrg admin.

    `peer channel update -f ordorg_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA`

For updating any application channel, just replace the step 7 by updating the application channel configuration block's `Application` section to add the new orderer organization's MSP there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting the steps. I have a question, I'm working using the Org configuration `OrdererEndpoints` and faced some issues when updating the `Consortiums` but I solved them after removing the `Enpoints`  from the org.json. Basically this > `jq 'del(.values.Endpoints)' $FABRIC_CFG_PATH/org.json > $FABRIC_CFG_PATH/org-for-consortium.json` Do you think that is needed step 13 if I'm using  `OrdererEndpoints` and not `Orderer.Addresses`?

Answer (score 0):

I followed above sequence of steps to add new Orderer Organization into existing network, but channel (i.e updating config change to orderer channel) update throw error like below,

```
    2020-09-29 00:53:49.794 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'e2e-orderer-syschan': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/OrdererAddresses not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

I modified-json blocks by using below setup calls (tried mix/match combination of this below json change steps)

```
jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}'":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config.json 
jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Orderer":{"groups": {"'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}'":.[1]}}}}}' modified-config.json ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config1.json 

jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Consortiums":{"groups":{"'${KL_CONSORTIUM_NAME}'":{"groups": {"Orderermk01MSP":.[1]}}}}}}}' modified-config1.json  ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config2.json 

LENGTH=$(jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses | length' modified-config2.json)
jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses['${LENGTH}'] |= "'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_URL}'"' modified-config2.json > modified-config3.json

cert=`base64 /hl-material/mk01-orderer/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/${KL_DOMAIN}/orderers/orderer.mk01.${KL_DOMAIN}/tls/server.crt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'`
cat modified-config3.json | jq '.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert'", "host": "raft0.mk01.'${KL_DOMAIN}'", "port": 32050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert'"}] ' > modified-config4.json
```

My network setup based on HLF 2.2 LTS with 5 raft nodes under K8s cluster.

I have successful setup with multi channel, multiple peer organization on 2.2 LTS (know how to get this in dynamic way without bringdown any network). But now looking for scaling orderer organization into multiple cluster/orgs dynamically.  Is any tip or update needed on above steps ? Thanks again
Mariya

Comment: Hi @RaspiRepo, I would suggest you to post a new question and you can add link to this question/answer as reference. While doing so, please also add the environment variables which have been configured to send the channel update request. For example, what is the `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH`, etc.

Comment: Hi  I created as new question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125207/hyperledger-fabric-adding-new-orderer-organizations-to-network