# Hyperledger Fabric adding new orderer organizations to network (HLF2.2 LTS)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I followed the steps mentioned here to add new Orderer Organization into existing network
channel (i.e updating config change to orderer channel) update throw error like below,

[How to add a new Orderer Organization to existing Hyperledger Fabric network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122349/how-to-add-a-new-orderer-organization-to-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network/64111617?noredirect=1#comment113375587_64111617)

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'e2e-orderer-syschan': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/OrdererAddresses not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

modified-json blocks by using below setup calls (tried mix/match combination of this below json change steps)

```
q -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}'":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config.json 
jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Orderer":{"groups": {"'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}'":.[1]}}}}}' modified-config.json ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config1.json 

jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Consortiums":{"groups":{"'${KL_CONSORTIUM_NAME}'":{"groups": {"Orderermk01MSP":.[1]}}}}}}}' modified-config1.json  ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config2.json 

LENGTH=$(jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses | length' modified-config2.json)
jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses['${LENGTH}'] |= "'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_URL}'"' modified-config2.json > modified-config3.json

cert=`base64 /hl-material/mk01-orderer/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/${KL_DOMAIN}/orderers/orderer.mk01.${KL_DOMAIN}/tls/server.crt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'`
cat modified-config3.json | jq '.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert'", "host": "raft0.mk01.'${KL_DOMAIN}'", "port": 32050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert'"}] ' > modified-config4.json
```

My network setup based on HLF 2.2 LTS with 5 raft nodes under K8s cluster in Orderer Organization A
NOTE: I have successful setup with multi channel, multiple peer organization on 2.2 LTS in dynamic way

But now looking for scaling orderer organization into multiple cluster/orgs dynamically. Is any tip or update needed on above steps ?
my setup Env:

```
KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME=OrgB
KL_CONSORTIUM_NAME=orga-Consortium
KL_DOMAIN=example.com
export ORDERER_URL=orderer.orga.example.com:7050
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=crypto-config/example.com/orderers/orderer.orga.example.com/msp
export ORDERER_CA=crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.orgA.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem


jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}'":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config.json 
jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Orderer":{"groups": {"'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}'":.[1]}}}}}' modified-config.json ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config1.json 

jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Consortiums":{"groups":{"'${KL_CONSORTIUM_NAME}'":{"groups": {"Orderermk01MSP":.[1]}}}}}}}' modified-config1.json  ${KL_NEW_ORDERER_NAME}.json > modified-config2.json 

LENGTH=$(jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses | length' modified-config2.json)
jq '.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses['${LENGTH}'] |= "'${KL_NEW_ORDERER_URL}'"' modified-config2.json > modified-config3.json

cert=`base64 crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.mk01.example.com/tls/server.crt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'`
cat modified-config3.json | jq '.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert'", "host": "orderer.orgB.example.com", "port": 7050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert'"}] ' > modified-config4.json

configtxlator proto_encode --input config.json --type common.Config >original_config.pb
configtxlator proto_encode --input modified-config4.json --type common.Config >modified_config.pb
configtxlator compute_update --channel_id "e2e-orderer-syschan" --original original_config.pb --updated modified_config.pb >config_update.pb
configtxlator proto_decode --input config_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate >config_update-diff.json
jq '.channel_id="e2e-orderer-syschan"' config_update-diff.json > config_update.json

echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"e2e-orderer-syschan", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat config_update.json)'}}}' | jq . >config_update_in_envelope.json
configtxlator proto_encode --input config_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope >"${OUTPUT}"


peer channel update -f modified_update_envelope.pb -c e2e-orderer-syschan -o ${ORDERER_URL} --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

any one experience this problem/know reference documents from hlf etc ?

Thanks
Mariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to sign the .pb file before the update [read more here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/channel_update_tutorial.html?sign-and-submit-the-config-update#sign-and-submit-the-config-update)

There is a [document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2.0/config_update.html#get-the-necessary-signatures) about the rule of this process.

Edit: I've just found [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/create_channel/channel_policies.html?highlight=orderer#orderer-policies) document of Fabric 2.2. It gives more information about the policy.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for pointing this out, some how missed sign-in part which I had on peer org joining process.